# I wanted to ask about AWS Data Transfer charges

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-route53

I have configured AWS a server with Route 53 and Elastic IP for a DNS. I am consuming API from here.
Website has multiple Images and these are coming from different Azure server.
Please guide me how my data out will be charged from AWS?
I frequently access my machine using temporary Elastic IP, will it also charge?

Comment: Data transfer charges will depend on what region you run in (which you don't say).

Comment: Hi, I have created Lightsail instance in Mumbai region.